# Previous Day in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

This may be a really simply one but cannot get this to work.

```
Invitations_Daily =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK ( AppUser[UserId] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( AppUser[DateInvitedID], 'Date'[DateId] ),
    FILTER (
        'Date',
        'Date'[DateId]
            = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'DateSelector'[DateId], MAX ( 'DateSelector'[DateId] ) )
    )
) + 0
```

I have a measure and want the previous days value. When I put in a -1 then ))+0 it gives me 0, instead of the previous day value. Is there something obvious I am missing or is there something else wrong with my data model etc ?

Comment: Got it . Make relationship from Date selector table to date inactive .Cheers.

Comment: DAX offers a function to get the previous day.... PREVIOUSDAY(), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousday-function-dax